# Delete 100+ posts or media files from wordpress faster than default?

Tags: posts, performance, bulk

The pages are running pretty fast but deleting many (like 25) posts at the same time takes up to one minute.

Same thing on the media library - everything is pretty slow.

I disabled already all plugins - MySQL 5.5/PHP5.6 and current Wordpress Version.

This happens on our hosting server as also on local development (in MAMP/macOS)

Comment: Have you tried using the wp-cli? `$ wp post list --format=ids | xargs -n1 -I {} wp post delete {}`. In addition you could also check your mysql slow query log to see what's going on there.

Comment: Neat idea - I will check this.